# Ubuntu 16.04 will not display on 4k TV

Tags: samsung, 4k-monitor

I have ubuntu 16.04 and its main monitor is a dvi supplied 1080. I also have a samsung 4k tv hooked up to the hdmi.  I recently upgraded from a samsung 1080 TV and it would display both monitors.  Now the only time I can get it to work is on a pc reboot and it will only display the image for a second on the TV then it disappears.  I tried switching to the proprietary driver from amd but I get no display on either screens when doing that.  I believe I had this same problem when I first plugged the 1080 TV in but I can't remember the solution.

Comment: Can you snap your keyboard & upload in question, to see if any action can be made just by keyboard shortcut. =)

Comment: It seems the TV itself was bad.  I exchanged it today for the same model and all is good.  Thanks for your help.